# How to convert a "Standard Portal" page to a "Static Content" page on WebSphere Portal 7?

Tags: themes, websphere-7, websphere-portal

I'm migrating a portal that's build on WebSphere Portal 6.1 to 7. Now I would like to take advantage of the new tableless theme architecture in Portal 7; which leverages **static content** pages instead of the traditional **standard portal** pages.

As of now I've already created the new theme and created some custom layout templates, so all that's left is for me to start converting the old traditional standard pages to static content pages.

In a attempt to perform this task I created a standard page and static page, exported the XML from the static page, replaced the content node's id of the static page with the standard page's id, and re-imported the XML. Now as a result of this I get the following exception:

```
com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlCommandException: EJPXA0150E: The resource was found, but in the wrong context. In the XML input, it is contained in page [ObjectIDImpl 'Z6_ADFR4GL108G230IJR66JLR00O2', CONTENT_NODE, VP: 6112, [Domain: rel], DB: E017-AABD4D600D004131809CDB9859370058], but in the portal it is contained in page [ObjectIDImpl 'Z6_ADFR4GL10O8ID0IJRSTU121GF2', CONTENT_NODE, VP: 6112, [Domain: rel], DB: E017-AABD4D600D0023D9809C9B771F44804F]. [component Z7_ADFR4GL10O8ID0IJRSTU121GF6]
at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.items.ComponentItem.locate(ComponentItem.java:495)
at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.UpdateEngine.tryLocateItem(UpdateEngine.java:383)
at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.UpdateEngine.locateItem(UpdateEngine.java:415)
at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.UpdateEngine.processItem(UpdateEngine.java:230)
at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.UpdateEngine.processItem(UpdateEngine.java:238)
at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.UpdateEngine.updateTopLevelItem(UpdateEngine.java:188)
at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlAccessHandler.fillObjectModel(XmlAccessHandler.java:345)
at com.ibm.wps.command.xml.XmlAccessHandler.endElement(XmlAccessHandler.java:227)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I've basically given up on attempting the conversion, so I started recreating the pages in Static Content format.

Comment: IBM Has provided a tool using that you can convert the Standard Portal Page to Static Portal Page format. Please check the below link for the same : https://greenhouse.lotus.com/plugins/plugincatalog.nsf/assetDetails.xsp?action=editDocument&documentId=5190EB71148A2EC485257B2400510466

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through My research I found out that this appear to not be possible, because of the way Portal handle the different types of pages. The *standard dynamic portal* pages are handled differently. These are configured at portal's databases, however the *static portal pages* are not, hence the error about the wrong context.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at layout templates that are modified with web dav. Further to this make sure you base your theme off the portal 7002 theme otherwise you have a whole bunch of work to do again when you move to v8

Comment: Hi Chris thank you for your input. I did create the custom layout templates through WebDav. Basically I just downloaded various layouts such as the custom layout and two row layout, modified them and uploaded them under a different name.